# Plotting graph of text file with strings and integers at the same lines

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using a txt data file of followig arrangement way:

```
{"alpha": 77.6, "beta": 135, "gamma": 342, "delta": 86.3}

{"alpha": 77.3, "beta": 140, "gamma": 332, "delta": 82.3}
```

......

(300++ lines below with similar arrangements)

A normal table should work with the following code(and that's what I want) :

```
def get_points(x,y):
    a = 'xyz/examples.txt'
    data = np.genfromtxt(a,delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
    x_axis = data[:,x]
    y_axis = data[:,y]
    plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()

get_points(0,2)
```

since I am trying to make a code which you can change the x- and y- axis as you like. However, it won't work in this case since the headers and the values are at the same lines for each of them.

May I know if there is any way to remove the headers or extract the integers out of the data etc?Thanks!!!

Comment: what is your x axis? just the line number or one of the channels?

Comment: For example,if I set x as 0,that means I want the value of alpha(77.6, 77.3...) as x-axis. 1 corresponding to values of beta(135,140...), 2 for gamma etc.

Comment: and your y-values would be?

Comment: Same as x-axis, according to what I desire to set(as the code said). The problem now is that the strings("alpha", "beta", "gamma", and "delta") are on my way for plotting graphs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet should work for your purpose.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from json import loads

data = {}
def get_points(x, y):
    a = 'xyz/examples.txt'
    with open(a, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            new_dict = loads(line.strip())
            for k in new_dict:
                if k in data:
                    data[k].append(float(new_dict[k]))
                else:
                    data[k] = [float(new_dict[k])]

    array = np.array([data[x], data[y]])
    plt.plot(array[0], array[1])
    plt.show()

get_points('alpha', 'beta')
```

---

Since each line has the same format, you can convert each one to dictionary and append for each channel its value. This will give you a sort dictionary where the key is the channel and the value is a list of values (in the right order). The only change is that you have to reference the channels by their names and not index, since the dictionary is unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the json package - clearly each line of your data is a JSON-formatted line

```
import json
    with open('data','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(json.loads(line).values())
```

If you'd rather have an array of dicts, rewrite the last line as 
    print(json.loads(line))

Edit: If you have an array of dicts, you can easily extract the x and y values you need

Comment: Thanks user192127! I used your suggestion with the .values() and now I got something like this:  dict_values([135, 86.3,342,77.6 ]) etc (many lines, and the arrangements are not in the same order as text file). May I ask how to make them in order, and extract my desired lines for plotting?